# general-create-definer and flycheck's "the function foo is not know to be defined"

Tags: init-file, flycheck

In my *init.el* file, I use the package *general* and the following line

```
(general-create-definer foo/leader-keys
```

and then later

```
(foo/leader-keys
```

I use the package *flycheck* to lint the code in the init-file and on that second line it gives me the warning

> the function foo/leader-keys is not known to be defined

I would like to ask how to get rid of this warning, by either modifying the code in the init-file or customizing flycheck's linter, or some other reasonable way.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some research, if using use-package when specifying the above settings it is possible to use the keywords `:define`, `functions`, and `:commands`. (More info [here](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package#byte-compiling-your-emacs).) Quoting from use-package documentation

> Another feature of use-package is that it always loads every file that
> it can when .emacs is being byte-compiled. This helps to silence
> spurious warnings about unknown variables and functions.
>
> However, there are times when this is just not enough. For those
> times, use the :defines and :functions keywords to introduce dummy
> variable and function declarations solely for the sake of the
> byte-compiler.

Comment: This is essentially a link-only answer. Please explain/summarize what that "more info" says that answers the question.